# elasticsearch copy_to formatted date

Tags: elasticsearch

I have elasticsearch 6.4.2 with a mapping like this:

```
date_of_birth": {
    "type": "date"
},
"prefix_search": {
    "type": "text"
}
```

and by using `copy_to` feature I want to add `date_of_birth` into `prefix_search` (which later to use for some text based search). When queering ES I get e.g. `1430438920000` for `date_of_birth` but when adding it to `prefix_search` I want to have it formatted to e.g. `2018.05.24` (or some other format, doesn't matter exactly which one).

In order for the formatted date to be useful when searching `prefix_search` one would have to craft a custom analyzer - please consider this as another problem.

What should I do when using `copy_to` feature in order to append the formatted value of a `date` property to the target property?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`copy_to` index to the raw source of your field in another field with the target field analysis chain.

You can either

1/ use a [script processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/script-processor.html) in a pipeline (but i think it will be a real pain in the a..)

2/ add the formatted data in the source you want to index in another field (like `date_of_birth_formatted`) and configure the copy_to on it

3/ use the same `date_of_birth` field, format the data before indexing and change the [date format](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html) on the `date_of_birth` field

Comment: Thanks but option 2 is not valid because one might already have some data which should be somehow updated in order to have the additional field. Option 3 I don't think would work at all because the date `format` is only used to *recognize and parse* the strings into a long value representing milliseconds-since-the-epoch in UTC (according to ES docs). 1 might be the solution but you'll have to give a valid example to prove it.

Comment: Option 2 seems valid for me, but it's a little bit nasty I think, because I have dozens of fields that I want to add suffix, e.g., adding unit to each field so that user can search phrases like `2km` or `20th century` etc. I don't want that many fields doubled. Option 1 I haven't master yet, and option 3 would also be invalid for me because I want them to be numeric in order to be filtered.